# How can I detect next page number of UIScrollView which is 'scrollView.pagingEnabled' = YES? in 'scrollViewDidEndDragging'?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, scroll

I searched several stuffs on stackoverflow like

```
CGFloat pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width;
int pageNumberToBeScrolled = floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
if (pageNumberToBeScrolled != 1) {
    // Do what I want
}
```

in

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate;
```

But this works only if I scrolled slowly so scrolling page is definitely moved over half of it. This doesn't work if I scrolled fast like swipe. I just scrolled like 30% of scrolling page, which doesn't satisfy the situation over there, but it scrolled to next page, and I want to detect it.

How can I detect or catch all `scroll-to-next-page` situations? Please give me some help :)

## EDIT

I working on this because I want to play a effect sound when scroll-to-next-page happens. I should detect right after my finger is off the screen and only for next page scrolling. I think if I handle this on `scrollViewDidEndDragging`, it'll be best for me :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm using this code to detect if currentPage is changed, it doesn't matter you scroll very fast or very slow.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
        static NSInteger previousPage = 0;
        CGFloat pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width;
        float fractionalPage = scrollView.contentOffset.x / pageWidth;
        NSInteger page = lround(fractionalPage);
        NSLog(@"%d",page);
        if (previousPage != page) {
            previousPage = page;
            /* Page did change */
        }  
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) I'm worked on your code for using to my project, unfortunately, this it not fit for mine. ` I want to `play an effect sound` as I explain my `EDIT part`.  I have to detect when my finger off the screen, but if I use your code, `/* Page did change */` part called `while my finger on the screen` and moving left and right to move over half a scrollView. Then my app keep playing effect sounds. Could you solve this on `scrollViewDidEndDragging`? If I handle this on that method, It'll be best :)

Comment: mstfbsnli ,  Your code finally help me solve my situation. Thank you for your endeavor ;-)

Comment: It seems to work fine but I ran into similar problem like that of steven -  I have to detect when my finger off the screen, but if I use your code, /* Page did change */ part called while my finger on the screen. Have you guys sorted out this issue? What can I do in this case?

Answer (score 1):

try like this  may be it'l helps you

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
        float fractionalPage = scrollView.contentOffset.x / 320;
        NSInteger page1 = lround(fractionalPage);
        NSLog(@"%d",page1);
}
```

Comment: 320 ? Is it going to work when the device is an iPad or when user rotates device ?

Comment: This code detect the next page. Thank you @Sunny. And @mstfbsnli, I think it'll work if `320` -> `[UIScreen mainscreen].bounds.size.width`. But the problem is, I want to catch it right after my finger move off the screen. It's just the same timing when `- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate;` is called. @Sunny, Can you help me with this timing?

Comment: `320` -> `scrollView.frame.size.width`?